# Example of Http Injection Attack

Tags: asp.net, security

I am trying to find a good example of an http Injection attack so I can understand this threat better....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean HTTP Header Injection? This is also known as CRLF Injection, or HTTP Response Splitting and/or Smuggling.

The OWASP Testing Guide is a good start: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Splitting/Smuggling_(OWASP-DV-016)

If you'd like more details I'd recommend looking into Amit Kleins work:
http://www.packetstormsecurity.org/papers/general/whitepaper_httpresponse.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The OWASP Web site is always a good place to start with web security problems: [OWASP HTML Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML_Injection)